# A working example of cleos push transactions

Tags: cleos

Has anyone ever pushed an array of transactions using the `cleos push transactions` command? If so, can you show how you prepared the transaction array JSON and a working example of the command being used?

Comment: Is there something that I left out to be considered a working solution? I could edit the answer to literally just show the format of the tx and pushing it. Figured crafting the actions provided a little more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: This is kind of a weird workaround since `cleos` doesn't currently support signing and pushing multiple transactions in a simple manner. The following answer requires `jq` command line json parsing library.*

The following example will generate, sign, and broadcast 2 **transactions** using `cleos push transactions`.

`cleos push transactions "$(echo "$(cleos push action eosio.token transfer '{"from":"user11111111","to":"user22222222","quantity":"1.0000 EOS","memo":"tx1"}' -d -p user11111111 --return-packed)" "$(cleos push action eosio.token transfer '{"from":"user11111111","to":"user22222222","quantity":"1.0000 EOS","memo":"tx2"}' -d -p user11111111 --return-packed)" | jq -s '.[0] += .[0]')"`

There's a bit here, so let's break it down...

The main command is `cleos push transactions "$(...)"`. This tells `cleos` that we are going to provide a raw transaction that is already signed and packed, and push it to the blockchain.

The rest of the command is a one-liner that is forming the packed and signed multi-transaction json.

The command inside the evaluator, will echo the output of the commands that follow it, then parse that through `jq`. Eg.. `echo "$(command1)" "$(command2)" | jq ...`

The first transaction is created with the following:
`cleos push action eosio.token transfer '{"from":"user11111111","to":"user22222222","quantity":"1.0000 EOS","memo":"tx1"}' -d -p user11111111 --return-packed`

And the second transaction is created with the following:
`cleos push action eosio.token transfer '{"from":"user11111111","to":"user22222222","quantity":"1.0000 EOS","memo":"tx2"}' -d -p user11111111 --return-packed`

These commands will prepare a transaction with a single action. It will sign but will not broadcast `(-d)`; the packed transaction result will be returned to STDOUT. To combine them together, we use `jq` below...

`| jq -s '.[0] += .[0]'`

So remember how we did `echo "$(command1) $(command2)` above, well `jq` can combine their output together. The parser command above is telling `jq` to combine the two transaction objects into a single array.

All of that should give us a result that looks similar to the following:

```
[
  {
    "signatures": [
      "SIG_K1_K7eWqZmnneUHhnhcR9r6LwNnXYSEqpv6HcE124nNfSL5eZADyTDGfXTprxH79cMgh74GAX5Fo9mYiiJQxCMp2cN8hSept7"
    ],
    "compression": "none",
    "packed_context_free_data": "",
    "packed_trx": "822f5e5d94f08b818c41000000000100a6823403ea3055000000572d3ccdcd0100000857219de8ad00000000a8ed32322400000857219de8ad00001057219de8ad102700000000000004454f53000000000374783100"
  },
  {
    "signatures": [
      "SIG_K1_Jz64RXE4FiX7VeDo9XacR2pGKbmN4uGygXy5ghwrUwyTDPN5ApyY4oc7RMkWSPpZmwzkStdUWUx4ZzNetWcV12E6KPBb2k"
    ],
    "compression": "none",
    "packed_context_free_data": "",
    "packed_trx": "832f5e5d94f08b818c41000000000100a6823403ea3055000000572d3ccdcd0100000857219de8ad00000000a8ed32322400000857219de8ad00001057219de8ad102700000000000004454f53000000000374783200"
  }
]
```

This is perfectly formatted for the `cleos push transactions $(...)` command.

Comment: Well that was definitely my screw up. I saw transactions and read actions. I have since updated the answer to reflect the desired multiple *trans*actions. However, I still use `cleos push action` to craft the transactions in this example. You could always craft the transaction by hand or some other method and then use cleos to sign/broadcast.